"would be"/ "is"/ "I think"
*Context 1:

A: Who is the best student in our class?
B: It would be/ is X

*Context 2:

A: Selena Gomez would be/is considered beautiful by most people,
but there are some people that think her beauty is just normal.
B: You are right. The definition of beauty varies between people.

*Context 3: My friend is a movie director. We are walking in a mall, suddenly I notice a nice song playing from a shop in that mall. I say to my friend:

This song would be/ is suitable for the movie you are making.

Question:

What is the difference between "would be" and "is" in these contexts?
What is the difference between " would be" and "I think" in these contexts?


It would be X
I think It is X


Selena Gomez would be considered beautiful by most people...
I think Selena Gomez is considered beautiful by most people...


This song would be suitable for the movie you are making.
I think this song is suitable for the movie you are making.


It's misleading to suggest that the (relatively formal) use of would be instead of is somehow implies I think rather than I know. In practice, That would be X is just a slightly formal alternative to That is X, but by default both assertions carry the same "truth value" (they're stating a fact). If there's any doubt, this would be conveyed by That might be X and That would probably be X, etc.

The only uncertainty about This song would be suitable for the movie you are making concerns whether or not the director decides to use the song. No real difference in "truth value" between that and This song is suitable for the movie you are making. But arguably This song will be suitable for the movie you are making more strongly implies speaker believes not only that it's suitable, but also that it will in fact be used.

With the 1st context: "That would be X" vs "I think that is X" What is the difference? @FumbleFingers

Like I said, semantically, there's no difference between "That would be X" vs "I think that is X" and "That is X". It's kinda "baked in" to human communication that whatever you say is what you think (you may be mistaken, but that might just be a matter of opinion anyway). Using the "conditional, circumlocutory" form would introduces an element of "distance" which primarily reflects "deferential hesitancy" (often, in formal situations). It doesn't really have anything to do with the "truth value" of what you (would) think. If you never use would like that, it would be fine.

It slightly depends on exactly what you're actually saying, but personally I can't see any semantic difference between "You are an idiot", "I think you are an idiot", and "I would say you are an idiot".

(2) and (3) can be seen as imaginary conditionals: "(If you asked people their opinion of Selina's looks), most people would say she is beautiful." "(If you wanted to use that song) it would be suitable."

“Selena Gomez would be considered beautiful by most people...”
Vs
“I think Selena Gomez is considered beautiful by most people...”
Is there any difference between these sentences?
